# Как адаптивно прибить элементы справа?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

У меня есть брейкпоинт, когда вместо списка ( см. рис. 1 отображается кнопка с дропдавновской менюшкой, но элементов в данном блоке у меня 3, то есть если б тут был чисто логотип и меню, то да, justify-content:space-between подошел бы идеально, но тут 3 объекта и по свойству у меня второй элементы выходит тупо по центру (см. рис. 2), как мне прибить элемент к правой части, при этом что бы при уменьшении экрана он сдвигался вправо вместе с иконками соц сетей? Заранее большое спасибо <3 Всех с наступающим
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно у контейнера убрать  justify-content, растянуть его на 100%, и у кнопки с дропдавновской менюшкой ставишь margin-left: auto;

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое <3 все прибилось)